# How can I make kinetic.js full screen background view

Tags: javascript, html, css, kineticjs

I found this awesome .js called kinetic.  I've been messing with the html, css for sometime now and am unable to set the container to full screen.

http://designobvio.us/v4design/demo.html

I've set all the parents to 100% height and tried a fullscreen jQuery.  Unfortunately still no luck.

I've paired down the code as much as possible for readability.  As you can see I've set the height to just 400px because it just goes crazy otherwise.  If there's any thing else i can offer as support, please don't hesitate to ask.

As a second request would anyone have any idea how to set the border to inside.  Or make sure that the width fits nicely with borders as is?

Comment: Your wrapper div is 10 pixels bigger than my screen.

Comment: I can smell the sweaty tennis balls.  Nice photo.

Comment: the picture isnt mine.  Any idea on how to set this image to 100% height ?

Comment: I don't know kinetic.  All I know are css properties `height` and `min-height`.

Comment: You could do something like `document.getElementByID('wrapper').style.height = window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position your `#wrapper` div absolutely and just stretch it in all directions with the `top, right, bottom, left` properties like so:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

With this method the borders play nicely with the positioning, but if you want to place them inside your container you can set the border style to `inset` instead of `solid`. Also, your control buttons will disappear so to make them pop in front of your image just set them to `position:relative` and give them a large `z-index` so they appear on top of everything else.

Comment: I cannot believe this worked... I never knew this worked.  Thank you so much <3